# Table Data Space Used Confusion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, table, size, heap

I have a heap table with around 700k rows.  The rowsize is 34 bytes: (1x BIGINT, 2x SMALLINT, 2x BIT, 4X INT, 1x SMALLDATETIME).  Why does Data Space Used say this table is taking up nearly 4000000KB (4GB) in Object Explorer Details.  It is compressed with PAGE compression.

I know I must be missing something on this calculation because I have another heap table with 12.7 million rows that is only taking up 1.5 GB and it has a row size of 356 bytes.  It is also compressed with PAGE compression.

EDIT:
I just did an SELECT * INTO to see what the size of this data would be in another table and it's only 28MB...

Comment: Where are you reading the space used from? Something like sp_spaceused that separates the data/index/unallocated pages? If not have you deleted a *lot* of data from that table at any point?

Comment: How many pages does the table have? `select sum(page_count) from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('dbo.YourTableName'), default, default, 'detailed');` (substitute **dbo.YourTableName** with the appropriate table name)

Comment: David Spillett: I'm using Object Explorer 'Data Space Used' column, though I also have a query that looks at the sys.allocation_units table and it's reporting the same sizes.

Comment: Thomas Stringer: 492145 pages vs only 3563 on the table I did a SELECT * INTO of this data.

Comment: Did you delete columns? LOB columns maybe? Rebuild the table and the space is reclaimed.

Comment: I believe I've found the issue.  This is a HEAP table and has records inserted into it every minute.  This results in massive fragmentation that is not recoverable.  Correct?  I just need to add a clustered index and defragment.

Comment: ...or rebuild the table, but yes a clustered index is going to work better in terms of page allocation/deallocation particularly if the clustered index is on an increasing column (like the date/time of the insert). On the down side, this can lead to a "hot spot" if the insert volume is extremely high.

Comment: I think I'll be okay.  6 records get inserted every minute, I did use the SMALLDATETIME in the clustered index.  Table is now 13MB from nearly 4GB.

Comment: Ok, well it seems you've found your problem.  492145 ~= 4 GB.  Agreed with @AaronBertrand's recommendation.  You should have no problem with hotspots with 6 rows/min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to create a clustered index on the table which immediately shrank the data size down to 13MB.  I found this out thanks to the following post on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336934/reduce-sql-server-table-fragmentation-without-adding-dropping-a-clustered-index

> The point is, you have substantial fragmentation on the Heap. You keep calling it a "table", but there is no such thing at the physical data storage or structure level; a table is a logical concept, rendered physically as:
>
> - either the Heap plus all Nonclustered Indices plus Text/Image chains
> - or the Clustered Index plus all Nonclustered Indices plus Text/Image chains.
>
> Heaps get badly fragmented; the more interspersed (random) Insert/Deletes/Updates there are, the more fragmentation.
>
> There is no way to clean up the Heap, as is. MS does not provide a facility (other vendors do).

Comment: Heaps don't get logical fragmentation. You were probably hitting [the issue here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913399). I suppose that might be regarded as internal fragmentation. I have no idea what random inserts in a heap are supposed to be. They always just go where there is space.